# How can I sort a portion of std::list?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::list<int> numbers = {1, 3, 0, -8, 5, 3, 1};
    auto positionInMiddle = std::find(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), -8);

    std::sort(positionInMiddle, numbers.end()); // This doesn't work,
                                                // Needs random access iterator.

    numbers.sort(); // This sorts the entire list.

    for (int i : numbers)
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Is there some trick I can use? For example if there was a method that swaps two nodes in the list, then I could use mergesort.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason to use a `std::list` in the first place, given this limitation?

Comment: Use `std::vector`. Problem solved. Or a find a good reason to use `std::list` and then implement the functionality yourself.

Comment: Yes, I need the iterators to be valid when insertions into the list are made.

Comment: You can swap two list nodes using a temporary list and `list::splice`:

Comment: Just don't forget that `splice` is linear-time.

Comment: @Mehrdad, no it isn't, not when splicing single elements

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Technically, if you read the sentence you just wrote, you'll see it makes no sense. :P It's still linear in the number of elements, where the number of elements happens to be n = 1.

Comment: @Mehrdad, If something is constant-time it makes perfect sense to say it is constant-time, you're just playing stupid word games. "Technically" 1 is a constant, so it's constant-time, claiming otherwise is idiotic. If you want to claim it's linear-time submit a defect against the standard and see how far you get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lists have constant time insertions and removal, so making a temporary list with `splice` to sort is quite fast insertion wise (still linear in copying elements, unfortunately):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::list<int> numbers = {1, 3, 0, -8, 5, 3, 1};
    auto positionInMiddle = std::find(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), -8);

    std::list<int> temp;
    temp.splice(temp.end(), numbers, positionInMiddle, numbers.end());
    temp.sort();
    numbers.splice(numbers.end(), temp, temp.begin(), temp.end());

    for (int i : numbers)
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `splice` is not constant-time.

Comment: @Mehrdad Yes, I added that. This is as good as it gets with lists, I think (If you don't want to write your own sorting function).

Comment: It's linear-time when splicing a range from one list to another, constant otherwise.  If you're prepared to write your own merge sort then you can swap elements using `splice` on single elements, which is constant time

Answer (score -2):

You can't use std::sort to sort std::list, because std::sort requires iterators to be random access, and std::list iterators are only bidirectional.

However, std::list has a member function sort that will sort it:

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I mentioned both issues in my question.